# While using Create table condition how can i give a specific numeric value to a column

Tags: sql, oracle, default

While using Create table condition how can i give a specific numeric value to a column

```
Column Name: Quantity
Data Type: NUMBER(4)
Constraints: Greater than or equal to 0;
Default Value is 0
```

Comment: I'd try `Quantity NUMBER(4) default 0 check (Quantity >= 0)`.

Comment: @jarlh relational dbms; sql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oracle

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?:

```
create table mytable (
  quantity number(4) default 0
);
alter table mytable 
   add (constraint chkQuantity check (quantity >= 0) enable validate);
```

Comment: Or even `default on null 4` from 12.1 onwards.